# Why aren't my objects that implement Comparable sorted?

Tags: java, sorting

my simple example (compiled working code) just does not sort fruits by their weight.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
        public int weight = 0;
        public Fruit(int w) { weight = w; }
        // compare this fruit to a given fruit f
        public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
            return (weight > f.weight) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // get some fruits (we intentionally create a box for 100 fruits)
        Fruit[] fruits = new Fruit[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            fruits[i] = new Fruit((int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1));
        }

        // sort fruits by weight
        Arrays.sort(fruits, 0, 10);

        // print fruit weights
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(fruits[i].weight + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

Why it is so?

Alright, in my problem (not about fruits), I have objects that are never pairwise equal, that is why I thought one object is either bigger or smaller than another. So how can I handle this situation when I know that 0 (objects are equal) will never happen?

Comment: if you implement the compareTo operation correctly (see below answers) and, by definition, two values will never be equal, compareTo will just never return 0 - no need to specifically handle something that will not happen. And if - for some reasons - it does happen after a while, your assumption will be wrong, but the implementation still is correct (if compareTo then returns 0). No harm done, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `weight` is never negative then you can try

```
return weight - f.weight;
```

instead of

```
return (weight > f.weight) ? 1 : 0;
```

to sort from lowest to highest value.

Comment: I like your solution because `return weight - f.weight` is much simpler than Integer's `return (weight < f.weight) ? -1 : ((weight == f.weight) ? 0 : 1);`. Do you know, in my project fruits are never equal, how can I use this fact to prevent returning `0`?

Comment: @SophieSperner If weight of fruit is always `>=0` and all weights are different then you `weight - f.weight` will never return 0. But in your example fruits can have same weight so I am not really sure how to answer on your comment.

Comment: That works well when all numbers are expected to be positive and/or small. But `-3 - Integer.MAX_VALUE` will erroneously return a positive number for example.

Comment: @SophieSperner `return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);` is the proper way to do it.

Comment: @assylias True, but I believe that we can assume that weight can't be negative, so for positive numbers `weight - f.weight` will work fine. In other case `Integer.compare(weight, f.weight);` would be best option.

Comment: @Pshemo In the context of a Fruit, yes I guess. But this can lead to cheeky bugs so I am always a bit reluctant to use that method.

Comment: @assylias Yes, my answer would not be correct in case where numbers could be also negative. I updated my answer to prevent that usage for future reader.

Answer (score 7):

`compareTo` must return one of 3 values:

- `>0` --> Bigger than
- `0` --> Equal
- `<0` --> Less than

Your `compareTo` method only returns `0` or `1`; fix that.

Comment: What bigger than what? I missed it absolutely.

Comment: 1--> This object is bigger (or after, if you want that spelling) the one passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Use the method `public static int compare(int x, int y)` from the class `java.lang.Integer` (since Java 7).

```
public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
    return Integer.compare(weight, f.weight);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use the JDK-supplied method for comparing `int` values, which also makes it crystal clear what the code is doing

```
public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
    return Integer.compare(weight, f.weight);
}
```

Prior to version 7 java, you have two choices:

```
public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
    return weight - f.weight; // terse, but slightly obtuse
}

public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
    return new Integer(weight).compareTo(f.weight); // ugly, but supposedly clear
}
```

My preference is the subtraction, because once you understand it, it's clear from then on.

Comment: No `Integer.compare` is not the best, because nested call to compare is crap, especially for comparing integers.

Comment: @SophieSperner says you... java will in-line it to the subtraction via JIT. It is the clearest code, and that counts for a great deal.

Comment: @SophieSperner It's clear if you're familiar with the pattern, but if not it could be puzzling to a new-comer. Clarity is very important. Also, if you were ordering in reverse, `f.weight - weight` is very similar looking code, but `-Integer.compare(weight, f.weight)` is clearer.

Comment: The subtraction works well when all numbers are expected to be positive and/or small. But `-3 - Integer.MAX_VALUE` will erroneously return a positive number for example.

Comment: @assylias Not being defensive, but... your comment is a case of letting dogma replace your brain: A) weight can't be negative, and B) if the expected range of values even comes within a few orders of magnitude of max `int`, you'd use a `long`, so in this context simple subtraction is perfectly acceptable. And you know it :) You always have to keep in mind where your code is, so you can apply he simplest safe solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `compareTo` method should return -1, 0, 1

```
LESSER = -1;
EQUAL = 0;
BIGGER = 1;
```